# Convert R Matrix to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, r, matrix, pandas, rpy2

I'm trying to convert an R matrix to a pandas dataframe. I am using:

```
import pandas.rpy.common as com
df = com.convert_to_r_dataframe(r_matrix)
```

And I get:

```
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

Strangely enough this use case is omitted from all documentation I have come across. I would also settle for a conversion of the R matrix to a `numpy` `array` - since I will want to iterate over the rows anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `numpy.array()`:

```
from rpy2 import robjects
m = robjects.reval("matrix(1:6, nrow=2, ncol=3)")
import numpy as np
a = np.array(m)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting confused about the difference between `convert_to_r_dataframe` and `convert_robj`. Use the former one for converting **TO** `R`, and the latter one for converting **BACK** from `R`:

```
In [30]:
from rpy2 import robjects
m=robjects.r('matrix(1:6, nrow=2, ncol=3)')
In [31]:

print com.convert_robj(m)
   0  1  2
1  1  3  5
2  2  4  6
In [32]:

m=robjects.r('as.data.frame(matrix(1:6, nrow=2, ncol=3, dimnames=list(1:2, 1:3)))')
In [33]:

print com.convert_robj(m)
   1  2  3
1  1  3  5
2  2  4  6
```